# Calculating the distance/bearing between two lat lon co ordinates

Tags: lua, distance, latitude-longitude, bearing

I've been trying to work out the bearing between two lat lon co ordinates but am having trouble grasping the concept.

I have been to http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html and have been able to change to distance code to work with lua, however the bearing code in the paragraphs under has me a little confused.

```
local y = Math.sin(dLon) * Math.cos(lat2)
local x = Math.cos(lat1)*Math.sin(lat2) - Math.sin(lat1)*Math.cos(lat2)*Math.cos(dLon)
local brng = Math.atan2(y, x).toDeg()
```

The naming of the variables (lat1, lat2, dLon) has me confused.

If my initial lat lon is:

Latitude = -33.8830555556
Longitude = 151.216666667

and my destination lat and lon is:

Latitude = 22.25
Longitude = 114.1667

What variables need to match up to which lat and lons?

Is the dLon variable refering to the distance between the two points longitudinally?

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the JavaScript code, `lat1` is the latitude of the initial point and `lat2` is the latitude of the destination point.

Note that all latitudes and longitudes must be in radians; use `math.rad()` for the conversion.

Also the math library in Lua is called `math`, not `Math`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
local function geo_distance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2)
  if lat1 == nil or lon1 == nil or lat2 == nil or lon2 == nil then
    return nil
  end
  local dlat = math.rad(lat2-lat1)
  local dlon = math.rad(lon2-lon1)
  local sin_dlat = math.sin(dlat/2)
  local sin_dlon = math.sin(dlon/2)
  local a = sin_dlat * sin_dlat + math.cos(math.rad(lat1)) * math.cos(math.rad(lat2)) * sin_dlon * sin_dlon
  local c = 2 * math.atan2(math.sqrt(a), math.sqrt(1-a))
  -- 6378 km is the earth's radius at the equator.
  -- 6357 km would be the radius at the poles (earth isn't a perfect circle).
  -- Thus, high latitude distances will be slightly overestimated
  -- To get miles, use 3963 as the constant (equator again)
  local d = 6378 * c
  return d
end
```

Input coordinates are in degrees, so
`geo_distance(30.19, 71.51, 31.33, 74.21) = ~287km`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function I've made and works perfect. Hard tested in X-Plane Flight Simulator. At the end there is a division of earth's radius by 1852, so the function returns the distance to nautical miles.

```
function GC_distance_calc(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2)

--This function returns great circle distance between 2 points.
--Found here: http://bluemm.blogspot.gr/2007/01/excel-formula-to-calculate-distance.html
--lat1, lon1 = the coords from start position (or aircraft's) / lat2, lon2 coords of the target waypoint.
--6371km is the mean radius of earth in meters. Since X-Plane uses 6378 km as radius, which does not makes a big difference,
--(about 5 NM at 6000 NM), we are going to use the same.
--Other formulas I've tested, seem to break when latitudes are in different hemisphere (west-east).

local distance = math.acos(math.cos(math.rad(90-lat1))*math.cos(math.rad(90-lat2))+
    math.sin(math.rad(90-lat1))*math.sin(math.rad(90-lat2))*math.cos(math.rad(lon1-lon2))) * (6378000/1852)

return distance

end
```